# Return Yes/No value from data in a large array

Tags: excel

I have 2 columns (Columns A and B) that contain following data:

```
Column A     Column B
User 1        In
User 1        In
User 1        Out
User 2        Out
User 2        Out
User 2        Out
User 3        In
User 3        In
User 4        Out
```

I am trying to get a result that would show all users that are still "In".  By this, if any user (from column A above), has at least one value = "In" (column B above), then the resulting value would be Yes, otherwise the value would be No.

```
User        Still In
User 1      Yes
User 2      No
User 3      Yes
User 4      No
```

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified that in the result list I have a list of the Users already populated, and then in the "Still In" column I need to return the Yes/No value

Comment: I get an error with the COUNTIF function, think it needs another set of parentheses in there but I still get a #VALUE! error when I add those parentheses in for the range

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: If my answer worked please mark as correct by clicking on the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use COUNTIFS

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,E2,B:B,"In"),"Yes","No")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(INDEX(B:B,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(A:A)*("User 1"=A:A))))="In","Yes","No")
```

Change the "User 1" to the user you're referencing.

Comment: This does not return what is expected.  The OP shows `User 1` as `Yes` and your formula will return `No`.

Comment: It works fine on my excel sheet. If the use is "In" it returns "Yes", otherwise "No"

Comment: Oh, but my formula is showing the last reference of In or Out... not if there is anything there. So you are correct Scott

Comment: Your formula finds the last entry for the user, and in the case of `User 1` in the test Data that is `Out` and as such it will return `No` for `User 1`.  The OP stated: `has at least one value = "In"` which would indicate that it is not what is last but if any of the entries are `"in"`

Comment: It is a great formula if that was the criteria.

Comment: Only one note, SUMPRODUCT is an natural array type formula and as such it will calculate all the rows of the  referenced data set, so in this case it will do over 2 million calcs for each time the formula is entered.  One should limit the scope of the data references when using array type formulas.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help on this, Scott your answer works perfectly